# Remove Feature from IIS 7.5

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

How can I remove an installed feature from an IIS instance? E.g., Url Rewrite? I couldn't find any menu item or something similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for `Url Rewrite`, go to Control Panel> Programs and features, search for  IIS URL Rewrite, and uninstall it from there.

Comment: Additional tip: you might not see it in the list of Programs and Features, you have to search for it